# Comment on deleted question

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[This question of mine](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/44115/is-this-a-picture-of-a-12-week-old-fetus) just got deleted for "*not notable, disturbing and as political propaganda. No thanks*", before I could answer the comment by Oddthinking:

> A common form of anti-abortion rhetoric is to make people see disturbing medical images without warning/consent. Whatever your actual motivation, this question read the same way, which may be part of the reaction against it. Perhaps you could explain your motivation better so people can understand what a good answer would need to provide

I saw a few days ago a drawing of a 12 week fetus in Twitter posted by an anti-abortion user, and I was looking for a *real* picture of a 12 weeks fetus. I could not find a reputable source with an *actual* picture, and this one (which had a picture and not a drawing) had no source attached. A Google image search showed only anti-abortion blogs using it. That's it.

Probably opening this post here in meta is not the proper way to address this, but I wanted to at least be able to answer Oddthinking why I posted that question.

*PD: I'm very pro abortion.*

Comment: You still did post what could be considered "a disturbing medical image without warning/consent".  I don't remember how specifically the question was worded; but that alone seems to be a big part of Oddthinking's comment.

Comment: That I did, I was not aware of that rule. In any case I wanted to address mainly the part about "*political propaganda*", I'm not asking to restore the question or anything like that.

Comment: Context: we've had a bunch of not so nice people post non-notable shock images for the value of political propaganda. Ever since we are not allowing (and aggressively hiding) non-notable propaganda shock images. So don't take my comment as pointing to your intentions (which I don't know and assume to be the best), but to the reason why the post was removed aggressively.

Comment: @Sklivvz Whether it's in OP's favour or not, using the net to search for such an image for verification or falsification is indeed an unpleasant experience of shoveling through a heap of nonsense and propaganda. Even those "debunking" or "fact-checker" sites come across as "barely helpful". Drawings, mislabelings, wax, plastics, clay models… I think the general "well, how *does* a fetus at this stage look?" should be addressable on SkepticsSE?

Comment: @Sklivvz I understand completely.